# How to force a window resize from the Linux side?

Tags: linux, terminal

The `screen` utility is famous for making PuTTY resize itself to the standard 80x24 window when starts. How does it do that, and how can I do it on command?

I've tried `stty cols 150 rows 40`, but that doesn't force the PuTTY window to resize itself. In the end, I want something like

```
stty cols 175 rows 40
dstat -tclypmsnd --nfs3 5
```

to autoresize the PuTTY terminal window to the 175 columns required by that `dstat` option set.

To restate, I'm looking for a command on the Linux side that will auto-resize the PuTTY window on the Windows side. `stty cols X rows Y` doesn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

It probably does it by disabling DECCOLM (132 column) mode. Try:

```
printf "\e[?3l"
```

`ESC [` is known as CSI (Control Sequence Introducer). `CSI ? <n> h` is DECSET, which enables some mode. `CSI ? <n> l` is DECRST, which disables some mode. More information about control sequences at https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

Some terminals may require a previous control sequence (DECSET 40, from xterm) to allow enabling/disabling DECCOLM:

```
printf "\e[?40h\e[?3l"
```

There are other resizing control sequences;

```
printf "\e[8;25;100t"
```